# How can I display a list of the top-voted answers?

Tags: support, answers, search

Occasionally, I like to look at the list of top-voted questions for a website, and read a bunch of them.  Since there are often great answers on poor questions, I find myself wishing I could search the "answers" and rank them by upvotes.

Is there anywhere on the website that I can see a list of the top-voted answers? I think this would be incredibly nice to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it does using the `is:answer` in search then sorting by votes.

> stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer

Comment: Yep, looks like that works.  I see Bobince's legendary "You cannot parse HTML with Regular Expressions" answer right there at the top!

Comment: And for ones own top voted answers, just add `user:me` to the search.